# Jmeter - Generating HTML Report

Tags: jmeter

i have run the existing csv file in Non-Gui mode and ended in error, An error occurred: Mismatch between expected number of columns:17 and columns in CSV file:13, check your jmeter.save.saveservice.* configuration or check line is complete
errorlevel=1
Press any key to continue . . .

I have done all the configuration as per the user manual but still i cant able to generate the report in html / dashboard

i can able to generate report on existing jtl file and while on test run but via csv file i cant

Someone HELP ME.....

Comment: Check the number of columns in jtl and csv. It should be same as per the issue.

Comment: please provide a problem in the way someone can reproduce...

Comment: columns in csv and jtl are same only eventhough the issue occurs @sunny_teo